# Plain Pandas Dataframe Pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that has six rows and nine columns. It is formatted like so:

```
               0           1         2
lat            33          33        32
long           66          88        78
input_string   string      string    string
status         OK          ok        ok
```

I would like to pivot it so it looks like so:

```
    lat  long  input_string  status
0   33   66    string        ok
1   33   88    string        ok
2   32   78    string        ok
```

I have been through quite a few examples, but I can't seem to exactly translate my needs based on the examples. How can I pivot the table like the above example?

Comment: isn't it `df.T`?

Comment: please post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what Quang Hong said, your question is not a pivot one but a transpose one - to invert rows and columns of a dataframe.
df.T will give the transpose of df